# Is there a way to add a custom folder to the "partials path"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views

I have several of my partials in a folder named `partials`, and I render them into my view using `render 'partials/name_of_my_partial'` and that's okay.

Anyhow, is it possible to set up things in a way than I could just use `render 'name_of_my_partial'` and rails automatically check this `partials` folder?

Right now, I'm having a `Missing partial` error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In rails 3.0 this a bit of a challenge, but looking into it I found that in rails 3.1, they've changed how path lookup works, making it much simpler.  (I don't know what exact version they changed it though, it may have been much earlier).

In 3.1, this is relatively simple because they've introduced a way to send multiple prefixes to the path lookup.  They are retrieved via the instance method `_prefixes`.

It's easy to tack on an arbitrary prefix to this, for all controllers, by simply overriding it in the base controller (or in a module you include in your base controller, whichever).

So in 3.1.x (where lookup uses multiple prefixes):

```
class ApplicationController
  ...
  protected
  def _prefixes
    @_prefixes_with_partials ||= super | %w(partials)
  end
end
```

Prior to this change, a single prefix was used for lookup, which made this a lot more complicated.  This may have not been the best way, but I solved this problem in the past by rescuing from missing template errors with an attempt to look up the same path with my "fallback" prefix.

In 3.0.x (where lookup uses a single path prefix)

```
# in an initializer
module YourAppPaths
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    # override the actionview base class method to wrap its paths with your
    # custom pathset class
    def self.process_view_paths(value)
      value.is_a?(::YourAppPaths::PathSet) ?
        value.dup : ::YourAppPaths::PathSet.new(Array.wrap(value))
    end
  end

  class PathSet < ::ActionView::PathSet
    # our simple subclass of pathset simply rescues and attempts to
    # find the same path under "partials", throwing out the original prefix
    def find(path, prefix, *args)
      super
    rescue ::ActionView::MissingTemplate
      super(path, "partials", *args)
    end
  end
end

ActionView::Base.end(:include, YourAppPaths)
```

Comment: Isn't it easier to use `view_paths` or `prepend_view_path`? Your methods looks awfully complicated.

Comment: `view_paths` are root folders, the starting point for template lookup, so it doesn't solve the problem.  E.g. if you added the partials directory to the view paths, then tried to render `somepartial` in `foos/index`, Rails will look for the partial at `app/views/partials/foos/somepartial`.

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't read the question closely enough. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: It ***is*** complicated, or at least too much so for what it does.  I'm fairly sure that's why they added modifiable prefixes at the class level.  In particular, I think it was to allow subclassed controllers to easily inherit their parents paths.

Comment: Could you point to the location where the code handling this is defined in rails? I found something in `actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/view_paths.rb` but it doesn't seem to handle `@_prefixes_with_partials`.

Comment: Scratch that, I re-read your code more closely and understand how it fits.

Answer (score 3):

*I haven't been able to find other resources than this SO question on this topic, so I'm posting about my efforts here.*

In **Rails 3.2+** (Also tested in 4.2), one can access and modify `lookup_context.prefixes` from within a controller action. So, to modify lookup of template & partial prefixes to include another path you can do this:

```
class MyObjectsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    # WARNING: Keep reeding for issues with this approach!
    unless lookup_context.prefixes.first == "partials"
      lookup_context.prefixes.prepend "partials"
    end
  end
end
```

This way, if there is a *show.html.erb* template in the *app/views/partials/* folder then it will be rendered. And the same goes for any partials referenced in *show.html.erb*.

#### What's going on here?

The method `lookup_context` returns an object of type `ActionView::LookupContext`, which is the object responsible to hold all information required to lookup templates in `ActionView`. Of note, it also gives you access to `lookup_context.view_paths`, which is **not** what is being asked for in this question but *sounds* like it should be.

#### WARNING

Modification of the `lookup_context.prefixes` array is cached for all future requests. Therefore, in order to use it problem-free, it's best to make sure we also *remove* any prefixes we add.

#### So, is there an easy way to do this?

Sure. For my own projects, I've created a module which I can include in any controller that needs this ability (or just include it in `ApplicationController`). Here's my code:

```
# Helper methods for adding ActionView::LookupContext prefixes on including
# controllers. The lookup_context.prefixes collection is persisted on cached
# controllers, so these helpers take care to remove the passed-in prefixes
# after calling the block.
#
# @example Expected Usage:
#   around_action only: :show do |_, block|
#     prepend_lookup_context_prefixes("my_optional_name_space/my_objects", &block)
#   end
#
#   around_action only: %i[index edit update] do |_, block|
#     append_penultimate_lookup_context_prefixes("my_optional_name_space/my_objects", &block)
#   end
module PrefixesHelper
  # Prepends the passed in prefixes to the current `lookup_context.prefixes`
  # array, calls the block, then removes the prefixes.
  #
  # @param [Array<String>] prefixes
  def prepend_lookup_context_prefixes(*prefixes, &block)
    lookup_context.prefixes.prepend(*prefixes)
    block.call
    remove_lookup_context_prefixes(*prefixes, index: 0)
  end

  # Sets the penultimate (2nd-to-last) prefixes in the current
  # `lookup_context.prefixes` array, calls the block, then removes the prefixes.
  #
  # @param [Array<String>] prefixes
  def append_penultimate_lookup_context_prefixes(*prefixes, &block)
    lookup_context.prefixes.insert(-2, *prefixes)
    block.call
    remove_lookup_context_prefixes(*prefixes.reverse, index: -2)
  end

  # Removes the passed in prefixes from the current `lookup_context.prefixes`
  # array. If index is passed in, then will only remove prefixes found at the
  # specified index in the array.
  #
  # @param [Array<String>] prefixes
  # @param [Integer] index
  def remove_lookup_context_prefixes(*prefixes, index: nil)
    prefixes.each do |prefix|
      if index
        if lookup_context.prefixes[index] == prefix
          lookup_context.prefixes.delete_at(index)
        end
      else
        lookup_context.prefixes.delete(prefix)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

As mentioned in the comments in this module, the expected usage for this module is to call the methods contained within via an `around_filter` call in your controller. This way, the module will take care of removing any prefixes it adds after the controller action has yielded.

For example:

```
around_filter only: :show do |_, block|
  prepend_lookup_context_prefixes("my_optional_name_space/my_objects", &block)
end
```

Or:

```
around_filter only: %i[index edit update] do |_, block|
  append_penultimate_lookup_context_prefixes("my_optional_name_space/my_objects", &block)
end
```

I've also included the `PrefixesHelper` module posted here into a gem that I use to add a few nice extensions such as these to my Rails apps. In case you'd like to use it too, see here: https://github.com/pdobb/core_extensions

Comment: Note: The code syntax above also assumes Ruby 2.1.2+.

Answer (score 0):

**Note: I've abandoned this approach due to some weird behavior and incompatibility with the multi_fetch_fragments gem**

If you'd like to prefix your partials for an STI collection, I've come up with the following monkey patch (for Rails 3.2, Ruby 2.2+).

config/initializers/partial_renderer_prefix.rb

```
module ActionView
  class PartialRenderer
    def merge_prefix_into_object_path(prefix, object_path)
      # Begin monkey patch
      if @options.key?(:prefix)
        prefixes = [@options[:prefix]]
        return (prefixes << object_path).join("/")
      end

      # End monkey patch
      if prefix.include?(?/) && object_path.include?(?/)
        prefixes = []
        prefix_array = File.dirname(prefix).split('/')
        object_path_array = object_path.split('/')[0..-3] # skip model dir & partial

        prefix_array.each_with_index do |dir, index|
          break if dir == object_path_array[index]
          prefixes << dir
        end

        (prefixes << object_path).join("/")
      else
        object_path
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In a view, use it like this:

```
<%= render @order_items, prefix: 'orders/timeline' %>
```

Where you have `app/views/orders/timeline/product_order_items/_product_order_item.html.erb` and `app/views/orders/timeline/subscription_order_items/_subscription_order_item.html.erb` partials available for each of your STI models.